# Returning variables to use in other functions in python

Tags: python, function, return

I am running into an issue with returning the month and day variables to use in other functions.

```
def date():
    date = raw_input("Date (ex. Jun 19): ")
    date = date.split(' ')
    month = date[0]
    month = month[:3].title()
    day = date[1]
    return (month, day)

def clone(month,day):
    print month day
```

Here is the output for the script:

```
Date (ex. Jun 19): june 19
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manualVirt.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manualVirt.py", line 12, in main
    clone(agent,month,day)
NameError: global name 'month' is not defined
```

Comment: `clone(agent,month,day)` isn't in the code you have shown us. Is there more?

Comment: Haidro, sorry about the "agent" part. that is not a factor in this. I just didn't remove it from the text.

Comment: You should either use global variables, or wrap these functions together into a class. That, or feed one functions return values into the other.

Comment: Please show *how* you use your functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably wondering how to use a variable in the global space when it is declared in a local space. use `global`:

```
def myfunc():
    global a
    a = 5

print a
# NameError: name 'a' is not defined
myfunc()
print a
# 5
```

Comment: @GregRobertDutertre Global variables should normally be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That is no reason that this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I do hope you mean the `global` statement ;). But anyway, in this circumstance surely there is no harm.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're returning a `tuple` from `date()` I will be assuming that this would be the thing you want to do

```
month_day = date()
clone(month_day[0], month_day[1])
```

And also the following line in `clone()`

```
print month day
```

should be

```
print month, day
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible  that You want to pass result of one function into another ?

```
month, day = date()
clone(month, day)
```

or You can unpack function result during passing it into second one

```
result = date()
clone(*result)
```

or even

```
clone(*date())
```

Comment: Don't you mean `month, day = date()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from here: `print month day`.

You need to separate the arguments by commas if you want to print multiple things:

```
print month, day
```

Comment: The error is a `NameError`, not a `SyntaxError`, so this is probably some error in formatting the question

Comment: @Haidro no, you can do `print X, Y` in Python 2 just like you can do `print(X,Y)` in Python 3.

Comment: @InbarRose arg, sorry, I meant in my comment "That would otherwise raise a `SyntaxError`, not a `NameError`

Comment: @Haidro undoubtedly, this is not the correct solution, but I was just commenting that what your statement appeared to be was incorrect.